# How to concatenate a value to a list when both are inside Maybes?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading realworldhaskell and I've come to [chapter 4](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html) where the book talks about "Safely and sanely working with crashy functions". I'm trying to write a safe version of `init :: [a] -> [a]`. This is as far as I got:

```
mySafeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
mySafeInit [] = Nothing
mySafeInit (_:[]) = Just []
mySafeInit (x:xs) =  ???
```

I get that I can't do something like `x : mySafeInit xs`, because that would be like doing `a : Just [a]` (right?). I've read about `fmap` though, so I tried this:

```
mySafeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
mySafeInit [] = Nothing
mySafeInit (_:[]) = Just []
mySafeInit (x:xs) =  fmap (:) (Just x) (mySafeInit xs)
```

Well that's guaranteed to work, right? Well no, and I'm struggling to understand why. Here I have a `Just a` and a `Just [a]`, right? Shouldn't I be able to use `fmap`, give it the function `(:)` and my two maybes, and get a `Just [a]` back?

After some googling I did figure out that this works:

```
mySafeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
mySafeInit [] = Nothing
mySafeInit (_:[]) = Just []
mySafeInit (x:xs) =  fmap (:) (Just x) <*> (mySafeInit xs)
```

but I don't understand why. Could someone walk me through this? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at

```
fmap (:) (Just x) (mySafeInit xs)
```

For `Maybe`, `fmap` is defined as

```
fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

Therefore

```
fmap (:) (Just x)
```

is

```
Just ((:) x)
```

Note that this is not a function; it's a `Maybe` value of some type (in fact, it's `Maybe ([a] -> [a])`). That's why

```
(Just ((:) x)) (mySafeInit xs)
```

is a type error (you can only apply functions).

In the second version of your code, you did

```
fmap (:) (Just x) <*> (mySafeInit xs)
```

, which is

```
(Just ((:) x)) <*> (mySafeInit xs)
```

Looking at the type of `<*>`, we get:

```
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Here `f` is `Maybe`, and `a` and `b` are both `[a]`:

```
(<*>) :: Maybe ([a] -> [a]) -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

That's why this version checks out.

> Shouldn't I be able to use `fmap`, give it the function `(:)` and my two maybes, and get a `Just [a]` back?

No, because `fmap` only works with functions of one argument. There is another function for two arguments, though:

```
liftA2 :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

Contrast with

```
fmap :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`liftA2 (:) (Just x) (mySafeInit xs)` should indeed work.

But it's needlessly complicated because one of your maybes is artificial: You explicitly wrapped your `x` in `Just`. You can simply do this instead:

```
fmap ((:) x) (mySafeInit xs)
```

By the definition of `fmap`, this is either `Nothing` (if `mySafeInit xs` is `Nothing`) or `Just ((:) x y)` (if `mySafeInit xs` is `Just y`).

Answer (score 4):

## Simple solution

I think you make things too hard/complex. You can simply consider two cases:

1. the empty list, in which case you return a `Nothing`; and
2. the non-empty list, in which case you can use the old init:

Or putting it into code:

```
mySafeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
mySafeInit [] = Nothing
mySafeInit l = Just (init l)
```

Now of course we have to trust that there are only two constructors for a list; and that `init` will only error when we provide it an empty list. Both assumptions hold, but can (although very unlikely) change in the future.

We can however use our own `init` function:

```
mySafeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
mySafeInit [] = Nothing
mySafeInit (l:ls) = Just (init l ls)
    where init _ [] = []
          init x (x2:xs) = x : init x2 xs
```

Now the Haskell compiler can verify that both functions are *syntactically* total. Note that functions can be total, but not syntactically: for instance because we can make assumptions regarding the structure of the data that the compiler can not check.

## Working with `fmap`

You provide a solution like:

```
-- ...
mySafeInit (x:xs) =  fmap (:) (Just x) <*> (mySafeInit xs)
```

A first aspect we have to understand is that `Maybe` is a `Functor`. A `Fuctor` supports a function `fmap` where we map the item(s) inside the functor so to speak. For instance a list is a functor as well, and we can thus map all elements in the list with `fmap f somelist`. You can see `Maybe` as some sort of list with zero elements (the `Nothing`) or one element (the `Just x`). So in case we perform `fmap` on a `Nothing`, we get a `Nothing` back, in case we perform this on a `Just x`, we get `Just (f x)`.

Here we see `fmap (:) (Just x)`. Since we thus apply it on a `Just x`, we have actually constructed:

```
   fmap (:) Just x
-> Just ((x :))
```

This is thus a `Just`, but it carries a *function* `(x : )`, not a value.

Next we see a `<*>` operator. `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is some sort of "multiplication" over an `Applicative` (a `Maybe` is an applicative as well). On the left side we have an applicative of functions `a -> b`, on the right side an applicative of `a`s. The result is an applicative of `b`s: for every tuple of functions and values.

In case we perform this on a list, we thus obtain a list that starts with the values all applied to the first function, then all values applied to the second function, etc.

For a `Maybe` we thus have a `Maybe (a -> b)` left and a `Maybe a` on the right. In case these are of the form `Just f` and `Just x`, we obtain `Just (f x)`, in all other cases we obtain `Nothing`.

Since we perform a recursive call on `mySafeInit xs`, we thus obtain the `init` of the remaining list wrapped in a `Just`. In that case, we thus prepend that result with `xs`.

An equivalent code definition is thus:

```
mySafeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
mySafeInit [] = Nothing
mySafeInit (_:[]) = Just []
mySafeInit (x:xs) | Just ys <- mySafeInit xs = Just (x:ys)
                  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand what's happening in your two solutions and I see that they work. However, could you address my question about why I can't use `fmap` as I tried to? I really want to understand why it doesn't work.